# Occassional (OAuthException - #200) (#200) User must have accepted TOS

Tags: c#, facebook-oauth

I am confident my application is coded correctly (at least mostly), as it works about 98% of the time.  However, about 2% of the time, I get what appears to be a valid auth token, but when I go to post a photo, I'm getting the following error "(OAuthException - #200) (#200) User must have accepted TOS".  I have retry logic, but it gets the same error three times (so it's not a freak communication glitch).

I use the URL facebook.com/dialog/oauth to get the token, and then I use the C# Facebook client (Post method).

The other questions I've seen posted with this error appear to involve consistent failures, indicating an application error.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that a person is shown the permissions page (on Facebook) and rejects it, so the user is then redirected back to your website, but with the Oauth error - which you need to handle.

Basically, I want to log in via Facebook, but I don't accept their conditions (eg. you might be asking for too many things). Thus I'll reject the login, and the source website (you) needs to handle the refusal.

Comment: Good thought, but in my tests, when I reject the authorization, facebook doesn't return an auth token- instead it returns an error and an error description.

Answer (score 0):

After finally reaching someone at Facebook to talk with, it appears this may be an issue on their side- given the massive parallel processing needed to handle their user base, it is possible the auth token provided was not replicated to all other servers by the time my app (from a different location) tried to use the token.

The suggestion provided by Facebook was to allow more time in the retry process- while it is usually handled within a minute, sometimes it can take up to 30 minutes to replicate to all servers.