# facebook long term token "(#200) User must have accepted TOS"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

From what I've seen no one as given a good answer to this question about using a long term token to publish contents in a Facebook page.

So, I've checked:

1. My user as permissions to post to that page
2. My APP as requested enough permissions to publish to the page
3. I've used the page temporary token to request the long term token to publish to the page

I've got the page temporary token with this GET:

```
var obj;

FB.api("/me/accounts",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
       obj = response;
      }
    }
);
```

obj.data[1] -> Has the temporary page token that allows me to get the Long term token

I've got the long term token with this GET:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
client_id={app-id}& client_secret={app-secret}& fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}

and when I try to post to the page I have a OAUTHException 
"**(#200) User must have accepted TOS**"

I am using Facebook SDK for Javascript.

Can someone tell me what the "**User must have accepted TOS**" mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're posting to the right ID after you fetch the access token? The implication is that you're trying to write on a user's timeline where that user isn't a user of your app

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but yes, I am sure that I am posting to the correct page ID, since I can POST to that page If I use my user, which is the same that was used to get the **{short-lived-token}**

Comment: Are you trying to post immediately after you got the extended token, or does this also happen when you try and use that token later? Because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095119/occassional-oauthexception-200-200-user-must-have-accepted-tos suggests it might be a timing problem (FB-side). If so, I’d suggest that you use the short-lived token to make your first post – and use the long-lived token you’re getting at the same time for the later posts.